# Can the presence of radon (Rn-222) be determined by testing dust?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, radioactivity

If a relatively unventilated area, like a basement, were to be exposed to radon gas (Rn-222), would the dust in the area possess a detectable amount of lead? Considering lead 214 is a decay product of radon 222, will a room exposed to radon gas possess dust with a detectable and differentiable amount of lead relative to a room that is unexposed?

Comment: Chemically not, as amount of 214Pb is unrelated to total amount of lead.

Comment: The dust, or rather walls, is better to be tested for 226Ra. And the best is usage to passive long term scanners of 222Rn, detecting alpha decays of gaseous radon.

Comment: The 26 minute half life of Pb-214 would seem to be a problem...